# Batch bills- Submission Id

Tags: netsuite

I need to grab the batch bill submission id (from different vendors) of the object from netsuite.Does anyone know how to do this?

```
 TransactionSearchBasic transSearch = new TransactionSearchBasic();    
            SearchResult resVendorBill = service.search(transSearch);
            resVendorBill.pageSize = 25;
            resVendorBill.pageSizeSpecified = true;
            resVendorBill.totalRecords = SearchRecentTransCount;
            resVendorBill.totalRecordsSpecified = true;



            transSearch.recordType = new SearchStringField() { @operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.@is, searchValue = "vendorpayment", operatorSpecified = true };
            SearchResult resVendorPayment = service.search(transSearch);

            if (resVendorPayment.status.isSuccess)
            {
                Record[] searchPaymentRecords = resVendorPayment.recordList;
                if (searchPaymentRecords != null && searchPaymentRecords.Length >= 1)
                {
                    List<VendorPayment> lstVendorPayments = searchPaymentRecords.Select(ep => (VendorPayment)ep).OrderByDescending(epo => epo.createdDate).Take(SearchRecentTransCount).ToList();

                }
            }
```